# Fixed element's width bug in safari?

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, viewport

My website has fixed viewport's width 1300px. And I found some strange behavior of fixed elements in safari in iOS. No other browsers do that.

So, I make a test page (code is down below). It has 3 divs - static, absolute, fixed. All 100% width. viewport set to 1300px. And there is a simple js that prints width of each div.
All desktop browsers ignore viewport, all divs are equal to each other and to window's width. That is correct.

Android's browser (standart and mobile firefox) sets window's width to 1300px and all divs' width to 1300px regardless of orientation. That is correct.

The problem is with my ipod and my friend's iphone. Top divs are 1300px, but bottom div (with fixed position) is **1280px**. And this happens only in portrait orientation. In landscape orientation all divs are normal (1300px).
Why is fixed div's width in landscape mode is 1280px? Is this really a bug in safari? Or i just missed something?

Code of test page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="width=1300" name="viewport" />
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript>
function updateInfo()
{
  $("div.test").each(function()
  {
    var t = $(this);
    var w = t.width();
    t.find("span").html("width = "+w);
  });
}
$(function(){setInterval(updateInfo,100);});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="test t1">100% width relative <span></span></div>
<div class="test t2">100% width absolute <span></span></div>
<div class="test t3">100% width fixed bottom <span></span></div>

<style>
*
{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
body{min-width:1300px;}
div{width:100%;}

div.t1{background:lime;}
div.t2{position:absolute;background:blue;}
div.t3{position:fixed;bottom:0;background:red;}
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with minimum scale. Default value is 0.25, my device width is 320
So,viewport width's maximum is 1280px. Setting properly minimum-scale in meta helps